# add key value to 2d array using foreach loop in php

Tags: php, arrays

```
foreach($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
        {
            echo '<table border ="1px" width ="50%" float:left overflow:auto>' . "\n";
            foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
                echo '<tr>' . "\n";
                $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
                $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
                $y =0;
                foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
                    $promptData[$x][$y] = $cell->getValue();
                    $cellIndex = $cell->getCoordinate();
                    $promptData[$x][$y]['Index'] = $cellIndex;
                    echo '<td>' . $promptData[$x][$y] . '</td>' .'<td>' . $cell->getCalculatedValue() . '</td>' . "\n";
                    $y++;
                }
                $x++;
                echo '</tr>' . "\n";
            }
            echo '</table>' . "\n";
        }
```

I want to store index of the cell in the 2d array I am using
$promptData[$x][$y]['Index'] = $cellIndex;
But it does not work can anyone help.

Comment: I am getting error as Array to string conversion in $promptData[$x][$y]['Index'] = $cellIndex;

Comment: As the error say try to print_r it to know its structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're defining the value `$prompt[$x][$y]` first as a value, then as an array:

```
$promptData[$x][$y] = $cell->getValue();
$cellIndex = $cell->getCoordinate();
$promptData[$x][$y]['Index'] = $cellIndex;
echo '<td>' . $promptData[$x][$y] . '</td>' .'<td>' . $cell->getCalculatedValue() . '</td>' . "\n";
```

Try assigning the value to an array element for the cell, then echoing just that array element rather than the whole array:

```
$promptData[$x][$y] = [
    'Value' => $cell->getValue(),
    'Index' => $cell->getCoordinate()
];
echo '<td>' . $promptData[$x][$y]['Value'] . '</td>' .'<td>' . $cell->getCalculatedValue() . '</td>' . "\n";
```

Comment: I am getting a error in your suggestion reagrding =>

Comment: Woops, had a typo, had a `.` instead of a `,`.  Try now

Comment: I want to ask one more question if i want to retrieve those values, so how can i do this.

Comment: It's in the answer.  To get the value use `$promptData[$x][$y]['Value']`, and so to get the index you would use `$promptData[$x][$y]['Index']`